How can I develop Neo4j style interactive knowledge graph UI in python?
I am currently working with knowledge graph project where I am able to create knowledge graph from unstructured data but now I am struggling with visualization of that knowledge graph.
Is there any way to display knowledge graph just like Neo4j workspace?
For reference I have attached screenshot below :

Is there any way I can achieve this?
If it's not feasible in Python but can be done in another language, that's also acceptable, as long as the UI looks like this.

I guess you want to be able to create a visualisation like that programatically in your own application?
The library used in Neo4j tools Bloom and Query (which is like Browser) has been externally released as NVL (Neo4j Visualisation Library). It can be used to do the layout and presentation of a graph.
A pure javascript version of the library can be found here:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/@neo4j-nvl/base

and here is a react version that is easier to use in case you do use react:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/@neo4j-nvl/react
Otherwise you can find a list of some Neo4j visualisation possibilities, including some libraries, here:
https://neo4j.com/developer-blog/15-tools-for-visualizing-your-neo4j-graph-database/

And now I read that you wrote that you wanted it in Python (I was a bit trigger happy in giving an answer). Maybe you can find something on those links anyway.
